# CD4007-based subthreshold MOS amplifier

Tags: amplifier, ltspice, simulation, cmos

I'm considering buying a pair of CD4007 ICs so that I might build a  subthreshold NMOS amplifier.

I've seen it discussed [here](https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/analog/article/21807652/whats-all-this-subthreshold-stuff-anyhow).

I'd like to build [this circuit](https://www.aldinc.com/pdf/SubthresholdDesign.pdf#page=5) depicting a simple subthreshold amplifier.

Simulating the circuit with random NMOS models with VTO (threshold voltage) around 1V seems to yield a modest yet visible amplification, whilst maintaining a gate-source voltage lower than VTO.

Doing the simulations in LTspice with the models of the CD4007's transistors ([models found here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/cd4007-specs-vtn-kn-channel-length-modulation.715539/post-4532558)) showed amplification of the input, but a much higher gate-source voltage than expected, equal to or   higher than the VTO.

Can such a circuit be built?

Comment: What does "VTO" mean here? Threshold voltage (normally denoted as Vth)?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that. The model uses VTO and I wanted to be consistent.

Comment: Where are you getting the CD4007 models from?

Comment: I used the model given here: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/cd4007-specs-vtn-kn-channel-length-modulation.715539/post-4532558  I suspect the weird results are because the level 1 model of the transistor doesn't account for subthreshold conduction.

Comment: Wow, an article that mentions [Bob Pease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Pease)!  I bought a couple of his *Troubleshooting Analog Circuits* books from him at a flea market in Silicon Valley a year or two before he passed away.  Read many of his columns back in the day.

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs  Yea, that's why I asked.  Haha.  I'll try to post an answer for you with some information.

Comment: You may find this of interest: https://people.rit.edu/lffeee/RIT_Models_For_LTSPICE.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the MOSFET models [from the link you posted](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/cd4007-specs-vtn-kn-channel-length-modulation.715539/#post-4532558):

```
.model MbreakND NMOS
+ Level=1 Gamma=0 Xj=0
+ Tox=1200n Phi=.6 Rs=0 Kp=111u Vto=2.0 Lambda=0.01
+ Rd=0 Cbd=2.0p Cbs=2.0p Pb=.8 Cgso=0.1p
+ Cgdo=0.1p Is=16.64p N=1
*The default W and L is 30 and 10 um respectively and AD and AS should not be included.

.model MbreakPD PMOS
+ Level=1 Gamma=0 Xj=0
+ Tox=1200n Phi=.6 Rs=0 Kp=55u Vto=-1.5 Lambda=0.04
+ Rd=0 Cbd=4.0p Cbs=4.0p Pb=.8 Cgso=0.2p
+ Cgdo=0.2p Is=16.64p N=1
*The default W and L is 60 and 10 um respectively and AD and AS should not be included.
```

The `Level=1` MOSFET model structure does not model subthreshold conduction in the weak inversion state of the MOS junction.  The parameter which defines the subthreshold conduction in `Level=2` and `Level=3` models is the "number of fast superficial states", denoted `NFS`.  You can upgrade your `Level=1` models to `Level=2` by first changing the `Level` number (obviously) and then defining a value for `NFS`.  You can set up a test circuit and play around with the `NFS` value until it satisfies your needs.

---

You can also attempt to convert the `Level=1` model into a `VDMOS` model, since it's a minor extension to `Level=1` and also includes its own way of handling subthreshold conduction.  This method is possible because `Gamma=0` which means the body effect is non-existent and you can therefore permanently tie Body and Source together (which is required for VDMOS).

The best way to start is to naively swap the model types out.  You can do that by changing `NMOS` to `VDMOS` (let's only focus on N-channel for now) and removing the `Level` parameter, like so:

```
.model MbreakND VDMOS
+ Gamma=0 Xj=0
+ Tox=1200n Phi=.6 Rs=0 Kp=111u Vto=2.0 Lambda=0.01
+ Rd=0 Cbd=2.0p Cbs=2.0p Pb=.8 Cgso=0.1p
+ Cgdo=0.1p Is=16.64p N=1
```

If you run a simple simulation using this model, it will show some warnings in the SPICE Error Log (CTRL+L):

```
* Unrecognized parameter "gamma" -- ignored
* Unrecognized parameter "xj" -- ignored
* Unrecognized parameter "tox" -- ignored
* Unrecognized parameter "cbd" -- ignored
* Unrecognized parameter "cbs" -- ignored
* Unrecognized parameter "pb" -- ignored
* Unrecognized parameter "cgdo" -- ignored
```

Let's start with the easy ones.  `Gamma` we already talked about and should be removed. `Xj` is a Level 2/3 model parameter only and shouldn't have been there in the first place...bye!  `Pb` is simply called `Vj` in the VDMOS model so you just need to change the name.

`Tox` is a little more complicated to explain off.  The transconductance parameter `Kp` is related to the `Tox` by the following equation:

$$
\text{KP} = \mu_0 \cdot \frac{\varepsilon_{ox}}{t_{ox}}
$$

\$\varepsilon_{ox}\$ is a fixed number for silicon dioxide, but \$\mu_0\$ and \$t_{ox}\$ are the SPICE MOSFET parameters `Uo` and `Tox`, respectfully.  The trick here is that you can define `Kp` directly, or indirectly via `Uo` and `Tox`.  However, the trick here is that when `Kp` is defined it overrides the other parameters.  This is a long way of saying that `Tox` is not used and should not be there in the first place.

The three capacitance parameters are the most tricky since this is where the VDMOS structure has the greatest impact.  `Cbd` is the easiest as it maps directly to `Cjo`.  `Cbs` is non-existent in VDMOS (remember: body & source nodes shorted) so it can be removed.  `Cgso` needs to be mapped to `Cgs` somehow.  `Cgso` is a per/meter-channel-width parameter and `Cgs` is not.  *This is where I want to pause and say we've already encountered many problems/errors with this original `.model` definition, and now we expect a per/meter-channel-width capacitance of 0.1p to be believable?  I'll keep going for kicks, but if you're reading this you should skip to the next section.*  I'm simply going to multiply `Cgso` by the `defw` which defaults to `100u`.  The final VDMOS capacitance parameters are `Cgdmin` and `Cgdmax`, but since `Cgdo` is so small we'll simply do the same thing we did with `Cgso` and apply the result to both `CgdXXX` parameters.

Now that the model is converted, you can add the `Ksubthres` parameter which defines the subthreshold conduction.  I would start at `Ksubthres=0.1` and then adjust to fit your needs.  Here is what the resultant `.model` looks like at the end which results in no errors/warnings:

```
.model MbreakND VDMOS
+ Phi=.6 Rs=0 Kp=111u Vto=2.0 Lambda=0.01
+ Rd=0 Cjo=2.0p Vj=.8 Cgso=0.01f
+ Cgdmin=0.01f Cgdmax=0.01f Is=16.64p N=1
+ Ksubthres=0.1
```

Note that for P-channel, you still write `VDMOS` but then define a parameter flag called `pchan` in one of the parameters.  See the built-in [LTspice help page for "M. MOSFET"](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/M_MOSFET.htm) for more info on this.

---

As pointed out throughout the answer, the original `.model` statements you acquired are quite suspect.  After perusing around the internet, I found a few alternative CD4007 SPICE models which you should consider.

If you want to start with a better `Level=1` to work through any conversion explained above, I believe this one to look slightly more believable:
https://cmosedu.com/jbaker/courses/ee420L/s15/students/lej6/Project/CD4007.txt

Subthreshold conduction didn't really get modeled well until the BSIMx series of SPICE model structures were developed and expanded on.  [Dr. Lynn Fuller](https://people.rit.edu/lffeee/) from the Rochester Institute of Technology seems to have put a lot of work into generating higher-level models for the CD4007 and other monolithic MOSFET ICs from Advanced Linear Devices.  There is a [paper here](https://people.rit.edu/lffeee/CD4007_SPICE_MODEL.pdf) and [presentation here](https://people.rit.edu/lffeee/SPICE_Examples.pdf) which includes `Level=7` models that LTspice supports.  A text file with the models can be found here:
https://people.rit.edu/lffeee/RIT_Models_For_LTSPICE.txt

Dr. Fuller also created a `Level=8` model for the CD4007, but I can only find the NMOS version within this slide deck:
[http://diyhpl.us/~nmz787/mems/unorganized/SPICE_MOSFET_Model_Intro.pdf](http://diyhpl.us/%7Enmz787/mems/unorganized/SPICE_MOSFET_Model_Intro.pdf)

Comment: Thank your for this wonderful answer!

Comment: I am familiar with the parameter K/Kn/Kp, but ksubthresh confuses me a bit. In the past I've used the equation $I_{D}=I_{S}\cdot e^{\frac{V_{GS}}{\zeta V_{TH}}}$ for fitting curves to measurement data.  How would I go about measuring ksubtresh?

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs  Unfortunately, because VDMOS is proprietary to LTspice, `ksubthres` is not well documented.  I know ngspice reverse engineered VDMOS and has support for it, so I took [a look at the source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/ngspice/ngspice/ci/master/tree/src/spicelib/devices/vdmos/vdmosload.c#l354).  There is a comment in the code that points to https://www.anasoft.co.uk/MOS1Model.htm which apparently was used as a reference to create the ngspice reverse engineered model.  Is this sufficient for you?  I haven't really done much with `ksubthres` besides play around with the value.

Comment: So I did some sims based on the things you showed me. And I am pretty much sure that 2 * VT * zeta = ksubthresh, where VT is the thermal voltage I can't really explain why, but  that seems to work in LTspice. This is how it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/wsQYHpk

Comment: The model/equation I reference and use is similar to: https://www.iannaccone.org/wp-content/uploads/magnelli_ijcta_20121.pdf#page=2.

Comment: I think for now using a VDMOS .model statement with ksubth set to 2 * 0.025 * zeta should suffice. Zeta is despite its weird name just an ideality constant for the exponential characteristic of the current.

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs  Thanks for the info.  All that does indeed make sense.  The \$m\$ parameter in that paper is called the subthreshold slope and is multiplied by \$V_T\$.  The ngspice source code also refers to `ksubthres` as the slope.

Comment: Thank you for entertaining my question and helping me learn something new :)